# Windows btsync: disable 3rd party services

Tags: windows, sync, bittorrent

How to disable 3rd party services in btsync on Windows, be exact `use_relay_server`, `use_tracker`, `use_dht` options available on unix based btsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the GUI is concerned: those options are located in the **folder preferences** for every single share: In the main window click the folder tab, and right click one of the folders:

[image: BTSync's Folder Preferences]